# How to add OneDrive as an attachment location in iPad Gmail app?

Tags: ipad, gmail, file

I have an iPad Air that has Office 365 applications installed on it. I use MS Word very frequently and my files are all saved to OneDrive.

I use the iPad Gmail application to send emails and I would like to attach my Word files (saved on OneDrive) to emails, but the iPad Gmail app does not let me select OneDrive files, just Google Drive.

I figured out that I can 'export to Gmail' Word files from my iPad Word or OneDrive app which is great, but there is no 'Save draft' option if I do not want to send the email right away.

**To summarize:**

1. Is there a way to add OneDrive as an attachment selection option in the iPad Gmail app?
2. When 'exporting files to Gmail' how can the email be saved as a draft without sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing this via iPhone but the same findings should hold.

**Question 1:** I believe no is the answer, unfortunately. The closest you could get to having this button is also having Google Drive, sending from OneDrive to GoogleDrive from inside of OneDrive or a third party multi-cloud app and then using the Google Drive attachment button which exists within the Gmail app. The 'export to Gmail' option you've already found within OneDrive seems like the much better solution to me.

**Question 2:** I believe the answer to this one is that it's not possible to save the drafts. If you want to work on the email later and hence don't want to send it immediately, the best work-around is to send it to yourself and then edit it and send to the final recipient from your inbox.

Sadly I can't offer a better solution but hopefully this is of some help or at least offers some closure to your query.

Best wishes,

JB_199

Answer (score 0):

just log into gmail account through web browser, not an app and tick a computer version of display, not a mobile. Once you do that you can send all kinds of files. Even in web browser and gmail without computer mode of display you can still send just images. With computer display mode you are allowed to attach each file in your OneDrive or GDisc or whatever cloud you use. :)

Comment: How does answer the OP's question?

Comment: Thank you, but as Allan mentioned, I would like to achieve this explicitly using the Gmail iPad app and not the browser.

Answer (score 0):

mail app is the best for emails on iphone but you cannot sign in on another app using gmail account as it sends the link only on gmail app and not in mail app.any solution to cancel the sign in verification process

Answer (score 0):

Copy & paste:

In the Word list of documents, share your document "To another app" and there select Copy.

In the Gmail compose window (this certainly works in the "Mail" app, surely in Gmail too), Paste your document. This works for any message, including a draft or reply.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem but I work around it by using "Mail" app from iPad.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review